# How to extract defined keys in a type with index signature

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, index-signature

**TL;DR**

**Question:**
How can I create a type converter that gets the defined keys of objects typed with types with index signatures?

---

I want to create a type "converter" in TypeScript, which gets a type A and returns a new type B that have keys as all defined keys in A and accepts only string as values, like in the example:

```js
type AToB<
   T,
   K extends keyof T = keyof T
> = { [id in K]: string };

const a = {
    x : {}
}

const b : AToB<typeof a> = {
    x : "here it works"
}
```

[image: b works]
*b works*

But when I use this in a object that already has a type with index signature defined, the keyof doesn't get the defined keys, e.g.:

```js
type AWithSig = {
    [id : string]: {};
}

const aSig : AWithSig = {
    y: {},
    z: {}
}

const bSig : AToB<typeof aSig> = {
    y : "here the keys",
    z : "are not shown :("
}
```

I tried it in the TSPlayground ([link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBpmAPGAuVAXzWLSgE8AHAUxgEEB1ASygAsBlJgcyVQywDaTACb4Y0AE5MwXALoEUhANwk0aUJFhxOPAoxYduvdFhjkFhADT9MALwuqyVWnQAqIAEIAeG6%20tYAaRhqbChqMGEIGABranIQADMYV15Y%20KTXNAA%20YxghUWkYAPlxKCkZGGU1DWgYACMxN08vChpE%20BzkEyxcAgAiVmoJWhYYAHcQCWiovABKPsca2DqdRvdvVup27W5OvlNyMQGhkdhhEGoIMAByWAmp-AAKPv8sRfBale4AWRBRPXWLWc2x0lhgfXIfRgAB9wbY%20ntuphDv0AJLXUQAGyYsRgoygIHGk2iMGxuMGwxeNhgtiOC0IQA)) and it doesn't recognize the defined keys in aSig.

[image: bSig doesn't work]
*bSig doesn't work*

[image: bSig works if I define the keys manually]
*bSig works if I define the keys manually*

Comment: You can't do it with an index signature.

Comment: If you're *annotating* `aSig` with type `AWithSig` then you're throwing away the information you care about before `AtoB` even gets a chance to see it.  Maybe you're looking for the `satisfies` operator instead of a type annotation, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBBgnN)?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz the satisfies solves my problem! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `AtoB`, but with the type of `aSig`.

When you [annotate a variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with a (non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) type, that's the type of the variable.  It doesn't gain any more specific information from the expression with which you initialize the variable.

So by the time you write `const aSig: AWithSig = ⋯` you've already lost the type you care about.

Presumably the only reason you annotated in the first place was just to *check* that the type of the initializing expression was a valid `AWithSig`.  If so, you can instead use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) on this expression to perform the check, and then just allow the compiler to *infer* the type of `aSig` afterward:

```
const aSig = {
    y: {},
    z: undefined // error!
//  ~ <-- undefined is not assignable to {}
} satisfies AWithSig;
```

Oops, I made a mistake and the compiler caught it:

```
const aSig = {
    y: {},
    z: {}
} satisfies AWithSig // okay
```

And now the type of `aSig` is

```
/* const aSig: {
    y: {};
    z: {};
} */
```

which will work as desired with `AtoB`:

```
const bSig: AToB<typeof aSig> = {
    y: "here it doesn't work :(",
    z: "abc"
}
// const bSig: AToB<{ y: {}; z: {}; }, "y" | "z">
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBpmAPAXKgXzSLSgE8AHAUxgEEB1ASygAsBlRgcyVQywG1GAE3zQATozCcAuvhQEA3MTRpQkWHABCcIR27J0WGGTkEANH0wAvfAFcwQqgDNJVITAD0HmFTFiQYgCEMPaOLmBuMGAgsPLEMBBwUIwQLlQQdEysekqq4NDwejyGWCaEFkY2hPGJyamM6ZnM7FxoXjBqBXB6csamCjBV8gMEMCqklDS0ACogmgA802YwANI+2FBUDhkA1lRkIE4w0zx7B0fTAHzFMPwACjCSq7IJUBJSMIoqnbAARvgzObzcjUQ7wa4GSw4fAAIhYvhozBgAHcAjsMrgAJQw5R5dQwX49OizBYgqhg7pcCG8IxlOEIx6wIQgdJgADksFRYh2MFwAAoYRUsFUYXBfsAcUR2j8CUTAQsUH1CAMhopPssYWQYTAAD4wGFWGHXNBAA)